# javaの情報隠蔽プログラム

Tags: java

大学の課題で、以下のような問題が出題されました。

> 情報隠蔽を行うために メソッドpublic void setColor(java.awt.Color c)を追加した TurtleTrap4 クラスを作成せよ．
> さらに，mainメソッドで TurtleTrap4 クラスのオブジェクトを作成して， setColorメソッドを呼び出してペンの色を変えるように変更せよ．

そこで、私は以下のようにプログラムしましたが、エラーが出力されてしまいました。

```
public class TurtleTrap4 {
    Turtle t;
    int x, y;
    int dx, dy;

    public void init(int xpos, int ypos, int xspeed, int yspeed) {
    this.x = xpos;
    this.y = ypos;
    this.dx = xspeed;
    this.dy = yspeed;
    this.t = new Turtle();
    this.t.move(xpos, ypos);
    this.t.penDown();
    }

    public void setColor(java.awt.Color c)

    public void step() {
    if (this.x < 20 || 340 < this.x)
        this.dx = -this.dx;
    if (this.y < 20 || 340 < this.y)
        this.dy = -this.dy;
    
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
    this.t.move(this.x, this.y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    TurtleTrap4 trapA = new TurtleTrap4();
    trapA.init(100, 200, 10, 5);

    TurtleTrap4 trapB = new TurtleTrap4();
    trapB.init(150, 250, -10, 3);
    setColor(RED);



    while (true) {
        trapA.step();
        trapB.step();
    }
    }
}
```

エラーメッセージ

```
TurtleTrap4.java:17: エラー: ';'がありません
    public void setColor(java.awt.Color c)
                                          ^
エラー1個
```

これはどういう意味なのでしょうか。

私は、javaを先週から授業で始めたばかりの初心者で、文法など理解していない点は多々あると思いますが、どこを修正するべきか教えていただけるととても助かります。
(主に、 public void setColor(java.awt.Color c)をどのようにプログラムすればいいかをヒントでもいいので、教えていただけるととても助かります。）

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 講義なり解説なりで教科書とか資料は指定されていませんか？(無ければそうしたものを聞いて)それらを入手し、読んでください。そうした準備もせずに課題だけ出されることは無いはずでは？ ネット上の記事としてはこれらが参考になるかもしれませんね。[代表的エラーとエラーメッセージの読み方](https://seiai.ed.jp/sys/text/java/jv01b03.html), [Javaエラーメッセージの傾向と対策](http://www.mclab.ics.ritsumei.ac.jp/lecture/java/tips004.html), [日英対照javacのエラーメッセージ解説つき](http://alga.no.coocan.jp/javac-emsg.html)

Answer (score 1):

質問文中のコードにはメソッドのボディが無いためコンパイルエラーになっています。

メソッドの宣言にはメソッドのボディ([8.4. Method Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4))が必要で、メソッドのボディとは、セミコロン(`;`)かコードブロック(`{}`)のこと([8.4.7. Method Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-MethodBody))です。

---

`setColor`メソッドはこのクラスで実装する想定だと思いますので、(セミコロンでなく)コードブロックを追記します。

つまり、次のような形になります:

```java
    public static void setColor(java.awt.Color c) {
        // ここにメソッドが呼ばれたときの処理を実装する
    }
```