# Rotateするごとに長方形の辺の色を変える

Tags: java

題名にも書きましたが、Rotateするごとに長方形の辺の色を
赤→オレンジ→黄→緑→青→紫
と変えていきたいのですが、以下のプログラムでは、長方形左下からスタートし、
赤→オレンジ→黄→緑→青→紫
と色が変化していくのですが、紫が終了した時点で（亀が長方形右上に到達した時点で）また最初に戻って（長方形左下につまりスタート地点に戻る）しまいます。

どんなプログラムにしたいかといいますと、紫が書き終わった時点でも、続けざまに、つまり、
赤→オレンジ→黄→緑→青→紫→赤→オレンジ→黄→緑→青→紫→赤→オレンジ→黄→緑…
としていきたいのです。

現時点でのプログラム

```
public class RainbowTurtle {
    public void draw() {
    Turtle t1 = new Turtle();
    t1.move(100, 200);
    t1.penDown();
        t1.setColor(java.awt.Color.RED);
    t1.go(100);

    Turtle t2 = t1;
    t2.rotate(90);
        t2.setColor(java.awt.Color.ORANGE);
    t2.go(100);

    Turtle t3 = t2;
    t3.rotate(90);
        t3.setColor(java.awt.Color.YELLOW);
    t3.go(100);

    Turtle t4 = t3;
    t4.rotate(90);
        t4.setColor(java.awt.Color.GREEN);
    t4.go(100);

        Turtle t5 = t4;
    t5.rotate(90);
        t5.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLUE);
    t5.go(100);

        Turtle t6 = t5;
    t6.rotate(90);
        t6.setColor(java.awt.Color.MAGENTA);
    t6.go(100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    RainbowTurtle rect = new RainbowTurtle();

        while(true){
    rect.draw();
        }
   }
}
```

このプログラムをどうやって書き換えれば、期待している結果となるのでしょうか。
ご指摘よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

whileの無限ループ中に`draw`をコールするのではなく、`draw`の中で無限ループさせれば目的の動作は達成できるはずです。
亀が

- 色変更する
- 直進する
- 90度回転する

という動作が繰り返し行われるよう意識してコーディングしていきましょう。

```java
  public void draw() {
    Turtle t1 = new Turtle();
    t1.move(100, 200);
    t1.penDown();
    //初期位置設定とpenDownまではループの外
    while(true){
      t1.setColor(java.awt.Color.RED);
      t1.go(100);
      t1.rotate(90);
      （以下略）
    }
  }
```

mainメソッド側の`while`は必要ありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても助かりました。そしてわかりやすかったです。